# Regex print all lines containing (specific character)(random characters)(specific character) in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Basically I want to find and print all lines containing two specific strings separated by a random number of random characters.

I know I could do this with a pipe and 2 sed commands but surely there is a more efficient way to do it?

EG

```
hello my name is phillip654 nice to meet you.
```

Where each username is enclosed by `hello my name is`  and  `nice to meet you.`

I want to print each line where this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/hello my name is .* nice to meet you./' file
```

Comment: Thanks for both the edit and the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E 'hello my name is.*nice to meet you.' YourFile
```

Comment: egrep and grep -E act nearly the same but could have small different behaviour. In this case, it will be the same